# How to declare a set of points for an object to move to and from? [Android/Java]

Tags: point, touch-event, ontouchlistener

What I am trying to do is create a handwriting application which allows a person to press on the object (circle) and move it up/down on a set path. If the user reaches the lowest point another circle object is created and another set of points is created to follow etc.

So far I have a onTouch event which moves my ImageView object (circle) to where ever the finger is on the touch screen.

https://gist.github.com/Temptex/9796403

How can i get my ImageView (Circle) object to go from Point A -> B smoothly using onTouch events?

Edit: A picture example of what I am asking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kSfe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created an algorithm for it.

Created an array of x integers and y integers and used a for loop to check if the object was to high (out of bounds in the y coordinates) and check if y and x were out of bounds in the arrays.

If it was out of bounds from the array of integers, set it to the current x/y array values. in the for loop.

If this helps anyone here is the code:

```java
private final int yCoOrdinate[] = {310, 360, 410};
private final int xCoOrdinate[] = {905, 890, 875};

// Get finger position
int x = (int)event.getRawX();
int y = (int)event.getRawY();

// View x/y co-ordinate on TextView
coordinates.setText("X = " + x + " - Y = " + y);

for(int i = 0; i < yCoOrdinate.length; i++) {

    // If object is to high set it to yCoOrdinate[0]                
    if(y <= yCoOrdinate[0]) {
        y = yCoOrdinate[0];
    }

    // Checks top left corner of A              
    if(y == yCoOrdinate[0] && x <= xCoOrdinate[0]) {
        x = xCoOrdinate[0];
        Log.d("Coordinate check", "X = " + x + "Y = " + y);

    // Checks if current x/y position if out of bounds and sets them to i
    } else if (y <= yCoOrdinate[i] && x <= xCoOrdinate[i]) {
        y = yCoOrdinate[i];
        x = xCoOrdinate[i];
        Log.d("Coordinate check", "X = " + x + "Y = " + y);
    }
}
```

I can now control my ImageView with in bounds.